# Apache htaccess redirect all 404 (files and folders)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I want to redirect to a PHP file all "404" errors. I used .htaccess from Wordpress as initial step. Works, but not when the path is a folder, means, had a "/" at end, I get a Forbidden error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /includes/redir.php [L]
```

If I try:

```
http://example.com/anything
```

works as expected, redirects to my redir.php. But if I try:

```
http://example.com/anything/
```

returns a Forbidden error.

What I need to do to redirect to redir.php everything that don't exist?
I need to change httpd.conf? I need a "ErrorDocument 404 /includes/redir.php" line?

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't actually a WordPress site?

Comment: No, it's a PHP site, I just used the .htaccess from a Wordpress site as a start point.

Comment: In your example above, is `/anything` a physical directory? Otherwise, you shouldn't be getting a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: No, there's no folder or file called "anything" at root folder (as example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a "ErrorDocument 404 /includes/redir.php" line?

Yes, it is far more preferable to use an `ErrorDocument` directive like this than trying to redirect/rewrite manually to an error document.

The defined `ErrorDocument` will return the correct HTTP status code (without you having to manually do this). And PHP will set additional variables in the `$_SERVER` superglobal relating to this error.

---

If you specifically wanted to rewrite to a file on 404 instead then you could do something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /includes/redir.php [L]
```

> but not when the path is a folder, means, had a "/" at end, I get a Forbidden error.

It really shouldn't matter if the URL "looks" like a folder, unless the URL mapped to a physical folder on disk. Only then would you get a 403 Forbidden if there was no directory index document.

Comment: That's it! Need ErrorDocument and remove RewriteBase. Thanks!

Comment: The `RewriteBase` directive wasn't actually doing anything in this context. The `RewriteBase` directive just sets the path used for relative (not starting with a slash or scheme) path _substitutions_. eg `RewriteRule ^ redir.php` (`redir.php` is _relative_, `/redir.php` is not). If you don't have a relative path then it's superfluous. (You see a lot of confusion over the `RewriteBase` directive, but that's all it does.)

Comment: Thank you for the info. Anyway, using your directives, it's now working. I tried other things too, and now I'm not absolutely sure if was another thing that solved the problem. But your help and info was really appreciated.